# A question about finding Lebesgue measure of a specific set I am unable to find

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a quiz question of previous year asked in my measure theory exam and I am unable to solve it.

> Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $$S_{k} = \{x \in [0, 1] | \text{ a decimal expansion of $x$ has a prime digit at its $k$-th place}\}.$$
> Then the Lebesgue measure of $S_{k} $ is?

I know the definition of Lebesgue measure and I self studied it from Tom M Apostol Mathematical analysis and Walter Rudin (very few online classes).

But unfortunately, I don't know how this particular question can be approached and I am struck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let $I’=\{x\in (0,1]: x\mbox{ has a unique decimal expansion}\}$. Since $[0,1]\setminus I’$ is a set of numbers admitting a finite decimal expansion, it is countable, so $\mu(I’)=\mu([0,1])=1$.

For each digit $i$, let $I’_i=\{x\in I’: \mbox{ a decimal expansion of $x$ has a digit $i$ at its $k$-th place}\}$. It is easy to see that each set $I’_i$ is Lebesgue measurable and $I’$ is a disjoint union of $ I’_i $. For each $i$ we have $I'_i=I’_0+i\cdot 10^{-k}$. Since $\mu$ is translation-invariant, (that is $\mu(A+x)=\mu(A)$ for each measurable subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ and $x\in\Bbb R$), we have $\mu(I’_i)= \mu(I’_0)$ for each $i$. Since $\sum_{i} \mu(I’_i)= \mu(I’)=\mu([0,1])=1$, we obtain that $\mu(I’_i)=1/10$ for each $i$. Then $\mu(S_k)=\sum_{i\mbox{ is prime}}\mu(I’_i)=\mu(I’_2)+ \mu(I’_3)+\mu(I’_5)+ \mu(I’_7)=4/10$.

Comment: I Accepted your answer but I was not well and hence couldn't read your answer.I have question: Please prove that I' is disjoint union of $I_i '$ and how to deduce that each set $I_i'$ is lebesgue measurable

Comment: @Tim For each decimal number $x\in I’$ there exists exactly one digit $j$ such that $k$-th digit of $x$ equals $j$, so $x$ belong to exactly one of $I’_i$, namely, to $I’_j$. The set $I’_i$ equals an intersection of a Borel set $I’$ with an open set consisting of numbers $x$ of $(0,1)$, whose decimal expansion which does not eventually has only $9$’s, has a digit $i$ on its $k$-th place and a non-zero digit at some its $k’$-th place, with $k’>k$. Thus $I’$ is Borel too and so Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of asking the same question would be: What is the probability that $x \in [0,1]$ has a prime as its $k$-th digit? Can you now solve it?

(There is some issue with numbers that have more than one decimal expansion, but I assume this subtlety is not intended in the quiz.)

Answer (score 1):

Often I've found that when confronted with a set whose measure seems impossible to guess, it's measure zero. Even if I have no intuition as to why a set "aught" to be measure zero; if I'm super stumped, it's a good place to start investigating.

Can you put an arbitrarily small open set around every element of $S_k$? Or at least, can you cover $S_k$ by $\varepsilon$-balls?

EDIT: The above advice is still good advice in general, but we can actually just brute force this. Note that $S_k$ only has primes at the $k$th place, not any place like I was originally thinking.

The only prime digits are 2, 3, 5, and 7. So $S_1$ is  $[0.2, 0.3)\cup[0.3,0.4)\cup[0.5,0.6)\cup[0.7,0.8)$ and $\mu(S_1)=4\times10^{-1}$. Follow the pattern to finish the problem.

Comment: I got your point in 2nd paragraph but can you please explain how the sum of diamemers of balls must be of measure zero? I got  cardinality of $S_{k} $ equals $\mathbb{N} $ ×$ 10^{\mathbb{N} }$ . So, how can you say that |$S_{k} $ | × $\epsilon$ = 0 ?

Comment: If you can cover it in countably many balls, you can make the $n$th ball of measure $\epsilon/2^n$. There are countably many primes, and countably many digits, so (unless I'm under-thinking something) we should be able to put something together. 

Wait. I think I just got it. I'll edit my answer with the solution.